# IEnumerable add item?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, addition

Model

```
public class ChartData
{
    public IEnumerable<Series> Series { get; set; }
    public string[] Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    // there is another types
}
```

I have two data as `ChartData` type

```
// I debugged the following, data is like my expected.
chartData = HighchartsManager.GetBranchsMeterReadingsChartData(); 
chartDataCustomerAvg = HighchartsManager.GetCustomerAvgChartData();
```

I try to concatenate series of these two struct like following

```
// chartData.Series.Count > 3
// chartData.Series.Count > 2
// I want chartData.Series > 5 (3+2), after following line
chartData.Series.Concat(chartDataCustomerAvg.Series);
```

But there is no change over `chartData.Series`. How can I add `IEnumerable` to another one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I add IEnumerable to another one?

You can't, in general. `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface - it's not always meaningful to add to it.

You can create a *new* sequence which concatenates two sequences, which is what your code currently does - but it ignores the return value. So you can write:

```
var bigSeries = chartData.Series.Concat(chartDataCustomerAvg.Series);
```

That won't change `chartData.Series` itself though. (It's not clear whether you really want to do that or not.)

Comment: But we know not if `chartData.Series.Concat()` method returns anything. The return type could as well be 'void'.

Comment: There's not really anything to stop you assigning the result of `Concat` back to `chartData.Series`, is there?

Comment: @Rawling, that still depends on the person who designed the API in the first place. It may not always align with what the OP is trying to do

Comment: @Aniket Sorry, that wasn't aimed at your comment.